# sticky top is working with jQuery in simple template but it does not work in wordpress theme

Tags: jquery

```js
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

            /*----------------------------------------------------*/
            /*  Sticky Header
            /*----------------------------------------------------*/
            (function () {
                $('#logo-bar').scrollToFixed(); // Fixed Navigation Bar
            })();

            /*----------------------------------------------------*/
            /*  Same Height Div's
            /*----------------------------------------------------*/
            if (jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.fn.matchHeight)) {
                $('.same-height').matchHeight();
            }
        }
    )
})(this.jQuery);


jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    (function () {
        $('#logo-bar').scrollToFixed(); // Fixed Navigation Bar
    })();

    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    /*    Same Height Div's
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    if (jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.fn.matchHeight)) {
        $('.same-height').matchHeight();
    }

    });
})(jQuery);
```

I have added two block of code one in simple HTML template and the other in WordPress but it does not work in WordPress theme and it work properly in simple html template I searched too much on internet and see different option but still I'm stuck and now I am compelled to come here for help.

Comment: consel problem Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scrollToFixed is not a function
    <anonymous> http://localhost/vitsol/wp-content/themes/vitsol_theme/js/main.js?ver=5.6:8
    <anonymous> http://localhost/vitsol/wp-content/themes/vitsol_theme/js/main.js?ver=5.6:9
    jQuery 11

Comment: Are you using the ScrollToFixed plugin? It's not part of the jQuery library.

Comment: Yes sir offcourse i m using jquery-scrolltofixed-min.js for fixed top

Comment: Is the second one your WordPress implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having your plugins, I can't say for sure.  However, there are issues with your jQuery syntax in the second block of code.

In latest jQuery, the `.ready` is deprecated.  The following is how to accomplish the same thing.

Additionally, your snippet has some extra brackets and close parenthesis.

```js
jQuery(function($){
    $('#logo-bar').scrollToFixed(); // Fixed Navigation Bar

    if (jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.fn.matchHeight)) {
        $('.same-height').matchHeight();
    }
});
```